# Why should I disable PHP's ini_set() on a server?

Tags: linux, php, security, php.ini

I'm starting to manage a VPS, and I have read that I should disable the ini_set() function. but I couldn't find a proper explanation on why I should do this. Any good well-explained reason?

Answer (score 2):

One of the main advantages is it takes away from the developer the chance to change php parameters that the system administrator may have set for security or stability reasons.

I often get code from developers where they have used ini_set to change logging or error_reporting, you don't want to have an accidental `display_errors On` in production

Comment: can a hacker exploit the capabilities of this function? Can it be a security problem?

Comment: Yes potentially, if the developer who created the code allows some form of user input(example: POST data, query string parameter) to be used when calling  ini_set(). By default no. But if a user, by manipulating user input data, then he/she could enable for example display_error and then could get some insight in your application or application data.